# how to add parameters to bluemix pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, pyspark, netezza

I am using pyspark in an ipython notebook and accessing a netezza database.  I am trying to do something similar on bluemix.  The problem is that in order to have access to netezza, I have to add parameters to the pyspark startup.  How can I do that on bluemix?  Here is how I start pyspark standalone:

```
$ PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" /usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/pyspark --packages com.ibm.SparkTC:spark-netezza_2.10:0.1.1 --driver-class-path /usr/local/src/netezza/jdbc/lib/nzjdbc3.jar
```

Comment: Usually in notebook interface, you should be simply able to add your jar using magic %Addjar -f <http-or-https-linktoyourjar>
Once you do this, you should be able to just use that jar or import that jar.
for ex.
%Addjar -f https://github.com/SparkTC/spark-netezza/releases/download/v0.1.1/spark-netezza-assembly-0.1.1.jar
I tried, i can see netezza driver in import statement but cannot 
import com.ibm.spark.netezza but running the statement cause serializable issues.

Comment: I tried %AddJar and I get ERROR: Line magic function `%AddJar` not found.  I think $AddJar is for scala notebooks and not pyspark notebooks.  I also tried $Addjar with lowercase j and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the parameters for starting `PySpark` on Bluemix.
The `%AddJar` kernel magic works for the Scala notebooks, only.
It does not work for Python notebooks.

The driver for Netezza `nzjdbc3.jar` has to be provided and supported on the service in order to make us of it. Currently, this cannot be done by the user.

**Update**:

`nzjdbc3.jar` is not supported out of box. You could submit feedback via E-Mail and ask for the driver to be supported.

Another possibility to enable the driver for `PySpark` is to put the jar into a location which will be considered for PySpark configuration.

First, find out your USER_ID by using the following command:

```
 !whoami
```

Then, get `nzjdbc3.jar` and put it to the following location:

```
/gpfs/fs01/user/USER_ID/data/libs
```

One way to put `nzjdbc3.jar` into the mentioned location is to use `wget`:

```
!wget URI_TO_JAR_FILE -P /gpfs/fs01/user/USER_ID/data/libs
```

After the driver jar was downloaded to the mentioned location, you have to restart the kernel. During the creation of the new kernel all files in the mentioned location will be considered for `PySpark`.

Comment: Is there any chance of the bluemix spark admins providing the Netezza nzjdbc3.jar?  I am finding that working on bluemix is crippling.

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you two possible solutions. I have tried out the approach with `wget` for another jar file and it was working for me.